# python type hinting, get the type inside a container type

Tags: python, python-3.x

Lets say I have a type hinted `List[int]`, how do I programmatically get the type inside the container?

```
from typing import List
x = List[int]
```

The container is of type `List`, but how I get what's inside that (`int`), is there a python api for it?

Comment: In the future, please always use the generic [python] tag along with any more specific python tags.

Comment: This does appear to be a duplicate @juanpa.arrivillaga

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The machinnery in Python's  `typping.py` annotates that as a tuple the `.__args__` attribute of the generated class. In your case:

```
print(x.__args__[0])
```

Will result in `int` being printed.

I did not locate in any of the specifications if this attribute should be a standard, of it is an implementation detail of `typping`, nonetheless it will work for modern Python installs.